# When I enter the code in the page jsp appeare the same code when run program

Tags: java, jsp

```
String getSname=request.getParameter("singer");
String sname="'"+getSname+"'";
String query=" SELECT singer FROM egypt WHERE singer= ' "+getSname+" ' ";
rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()) {
    out.print("<br>singer : " + rs.getString ("singer") );
```

When I enter the code in the page jsp appeare the same code when run program

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: You mean you want to have that output on the JSP page, I think.

Comment: when correct the code apeare the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may cause the problem.

- single quotes are added two times around the `getSname`.
- spaces are added around the `getSname`.

Look at the code again.

```
String sname="'"+getSname+"'"; // Single quote here

// again single quote is added here along with spaces around it
String query=" SELECT singer FROM egypt WHERE singer= ' "+getSname+" ' ";
```

Comment: after correct the code appear the same the error @Braj